# Using Correlation for mouse gesture recognition

Tags: statistics, linear-programming, correlation, pattern-recognition

I am in need to build a mouse gesture recognition system which will compare given recognition to the the gestures in training data and will say where a given gesture best fits.

I am planning to use correlation to accomplish this. I would run Correlation on given input against all the gestures in training data and will select the action associated to the gesture with best correlation co-efficient (and cross a threshold).

I am not sure how robust correlation is for this purpose, so need your insight into this. 
Also please suggest if you think I should better be using something other than Correlation...

Regards,

Microkernel

PS: I am more of a programmer than a mathematician :(

Comment: hey, any response on our answers? be fair

Answer (score 1):

Your question is a little too general. It corresponds (assuming you have a fixed database of already classified data) to the most general **supervised classication** problem, for which there are tons of algorithms - the nearest neighbour rule is perhaps the most simple. But in any case, you  always will need to define  a "good" way of measure "distances" (among data items - gestures in your case) ;  you'll want  to try to minimize that distance, (or maximize the correlation, what is conceptually equivalent). The difficult thing is to define a good representation of your data that leads to a nice (to compute and to perform) distance function. (Read eg [Duda & Hart](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/0471056693))

Answer (score 0):

Before re-inventing the wheel, I would read the literature. There are some links to papers and software libraries on Wikipedia: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pointing_device_gesture

Answer (score 0):

It is not possible to simply correlate two sets of data of uneven sizes unless you approximate some points or do some other hacks.

**Dynamic time warping** is used for this among other methods. It is not too difficult to understand and implement, and there are plenty of providing libraries out there.

http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dynamic_time_warping